# How to quantify the similarity between two distributions estimated from two sets of samples?

Tags: probability, statistics

Let's say we have two sets of samples $\mathcal{D}_1$ and $\mathcal{D}_2$. Their sample sizes can be identical or not indentical, but both are large enough. Then we can obtain their distributions estimated from the samples using estimation methods such as kernel density estimator. Denote distribution $P_1$ corresponding to $\mathcal{D}_1$, and $P_2$ corresponding to $\mathcal{D}_2$. My question is: how to measure the similarity between the estimated distributions $P_1$ and $P_2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possible ways. Here are two that are in common usage.
Both convert the estimated density functions to CDFs.

One method is to look for the maximum discrepancy (absolute difference)
between the two CDFs (vertical, horizontal, or at a 45-degree angle).
Look at the test statistic of the Kolmogorov-Smirnov goodness-of-fit
statistic for an example. [Google 'Kolmogorov Smirnov test'.]

A second method is to integrate $|F_1(x) - F_2(x)|$, in effect finding
the area bounded by the two CDFs. The Cramer-von Mises goodness-of-fit 
statistic uses this idea.

I'm sure there must be many other measures of difference in use, but these may be the most widely used.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. I am new at statistics. Can you give me a small example to illustrate your mentioned methods. Matlab platform is preferred.

Comment: Matlab not available. Best to start with Wikipedia articles on these two topics.